# display row from database table and post it to another table . select row return 1 and not selected row return 0 into present status column

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, asp.net-mvc-5

I want functionality as in the below image:

[image]

I want to display data from database table within a html table including checkbox beside every row and store those data into another table. Checked data and unchecked both will be stored but checked data return 1 and unchecked data return 0 in is_selected column. I am using SQL Server 2014 and my project ASP.NET_MVC(5) Visual Studio 2017.

**View**

```
@using AttendenceSystem.Models;
@model IEnumerable<CsteY4_T2_Students>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Multimedia Communication Students";
}

<div style="font-family:Arial">

    <h2>Multimedia Communication Students</h2>
    <form>

        <table border="1" id="tblList">
            <tr>
                <th>Student Id</th>
                <th>Student Name</th>
                <th>Present Status</th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (CsteY4_T2_Students cstey4t2studens in @Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td class="num">@cstey4t2studens.StudentId</td>
                    <td class="num">@cstey4t2studens.StudentName</td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="chkStudent" value="@cstey4t2studens.StudentId" type="checkbox" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

            }

        </table>
        <input type="submit"  id="btnSave" class="addValue" value="Save" />
    </form>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('.addValue').click(tallyValues);

    function tallyValues() {

            $('#btnSave').on('click', function () {
                var list = [];
                $('input[name="chkStudent"]').each(function () {
                    console.log($(this).val());
                    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                        list.push({ 'StudentId': $(this).val(), 'PresentValid': true })
                    }
                    else {
                        list.push({ 'StudentId': $(this).val(), 'PresentValid': false })
                    }
                });
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../CsteY4T2Students/SaveStudent",
                    data: { list: list },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log('saved');
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log('error');
                    },
                    complete: function () {

                    }
                });
            });
    };
</script>
```

**controller code:**

```
        public class CsteY4T2StudentsController : Controller
        {
            // GET: CsteY4T2Students
            public ActionResult Cstey4t2students(string SubjectCode)
            {
                DataRetrive dataretrive = new DataRetrive();
                List<CsteY4_T2_Students> cstey4t2students=dataretrive.Cstey4t2studens.Where(sc => sc.SubjectCode == SubjectCode).ToList();
                return View(cstey4t2students);

            }
            public JsonResult SaveStudent(List<Student> list)
            {
                return Json(1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

**Model Class:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace AttendenceSystem.Models
{
    [Table("tbleMultimediaCommunication")]
    public class Student
    {
        [Key]

        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public bool PresentValid { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried already? Please post specific problem you are facing when achieving the above functionality.

Comment: Actually I want to display data from data base table  within a html table including checkbox beside every row and store those data into another table checked data and unchecked   both will be stored but checked data return 1 and unchecked data return 0 in is_selected column . I want to know the procedure . I can't understand how i do it . Here a picture is added . If you see it you will completely understand actually what i want to do . Thank you

Comment: i put your all code correctly and design database according to your concept .  But can't understand where (script in view) code will be past and how i have to write code ? is there any java script or jquery and ajax reference need ? what will be the code of the (url: "../CsteY4T2Students/SaveStudent") in SaveStudent.cshtml ? thank you

Comment: Yes you will need jquery reference. You cannot expect answer for complete functionality for you here. You need to learn yourself. You must go through more tutorials to learn more.

Comment: if you just hints It will be grateful. In SaveStudent.cshtml i will write my own code according to my concept but  your (script in view) code will be (my display view ) file . is it right ?

Comment: Yes. Put that script in View file. It should work. Try it out :)

Comment: Did you happen to get it right?

Comment: no .... i still can't solve

Comment: I update my question ... still i do what .... thank  you. You r great teacher and friendly minded among i have ever seen

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Frankly, here in SO you need to ask specific problems were you get stuck and can't get help from web. Its not a tutorial website.

Comment: it's not show any error . When i click save it not save to database ... and my display table page not change.

Comment: Button not work ... when i click save . its not save . Actually I search in google but not get any proper way and see tutorial . I am a new learner . For the reason I ask you many time . If any special one ... may be he/she will solve it easily . But it seems harder to me. Please see my view .is this right ?

Comment: Hello @User3250 I thik i am close to the answer . Now problem is everything ok but data not save to database and in url :
http://localhost:2414/CsteY4T2Students/Cstey4t2students?chkStudent=1&chkStudent=2&chkStudent=3 show  but save or error not display

Comment: Seems you are making a **GET** request. You should make a **POST** request. Pls raise a new question for the same. IMHO You can't ask every issue you get in same question. Also, accept my answer below as it worked for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understand here is a sample, haven't tested but should take you in right direction:

**Your View - Added table ID, take a look at check box**

```
<table border="1" id="tblList">
    <tr>
    <th>Student Id</th>
    <th>Student Name</th>
    <th>Present Status</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (CsteY4_T2_Students cstey4t2studens in @Model)
    {
    <tr>
    <td>@cstey4t2studens.StudentId</td>
    <td>@cstey4t2studens.StudentName</td>
    <td> 
        <input name="chkStudent" value="@cstey4t2studens.StudentId" type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
<button type="button" id="btnSave">Save</button>
```

**Script in View**

```
$(function () {

    $('#btnSave').on('click', function () {
        var list = [];
        $('input[name="chkStudent"]').each(function () {
            console.log($(this).val());
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                list.push({ 'StudentId': $(this).val(), 'PresentValid': true })
            }
            else {
                list.push({ 'StudentId': $(this).val(), 'PresentValid': false })
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../CsteY4T2Students/SaveStudent",               
            data: { list: list },
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('saved');
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log('error');
            },
            complete: function () {

            }
        });
    });
});
```

**In Controller**

```
 public JsonResult SaveStudent(List<Student> list)
    {
        return Json(1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Assuming you have StudentClass as below:

```
class Student
{
   public int StudentId {get;set;}
   public bool PresentValid {get;set}
}
```